# D3JS Bubble Chart, simpler version

Tags: javascript, json

I'm very inexperienced with JS and trying to figure out, how to modify this D3JS [Bubble Chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269) to be used with a much simpler JSON input. At the moment, it takes input as such:

```
{"name": "flare", "children": [
    {"name": "analytics","children": [
        {"name": "cluster","children": [
            {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
            {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812}
        ]}
    ]}
]}
```

I simpy want it to take this input instead:

```
{"name":"Name1","count":3},
{"name":"Name2","count":7}
```

Can anyone help me do that, or just to understand their code, so I can modify it myself? :)